# AngularJS MultiSelect crashing app at initialization

Tags: javascript, angularjs, npm, angularjs-directive, multipleselection

I'm trying to use [AngularJs Multiselect](http://isteven.github.io/angular-multi-select/#/main), however, even following the tutorial the app won't initialize, giving me the following errors:

[image]

**These are my items**

**app.js:**

```
angular.module('MyApp', [
 'ngRoute', 
 'isteven-multi-select',
 'reports',
 'resource',
 'authManager',
 'ui.bootstrap'
])
```

**index.html:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/isteven-angular-multiselect/isteven-multi-select.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/isteven-angular-multiselect/isteven-multi-select.js"></script>
```

Or should I add my 'isteven-multi-select' inside of the controller of my reports like this?

[image]

Comment: did you install the module on the server?

Comment: @MaxAlexanderHanna no, I didn't. The places where I inserted something related to the module were: app.js and index.html